# How to burn DVD after selecting "use it like a USB flash"?

Tags: dvd-burning

I inserted an empty DVD for burning. I use Windows 10. I got two options and I wanted to try the option that makes me use the DVD as if it's a USB flash drive. The DVD didn't work on my other PC. So, I would like to select the other option which enables me to write or burn files (the traditional way).

Where can I find this menu again to select the other option?

Answer (score 1):

Use another DVD <strike>(or format this one)</strike> and then copy the files back over.

Comment: Once you've formatted a DVDR disc for one mode of operation _if it's a USB flash drive_ you can't change modes for that disc, so you need to use a new disc.

Comment: @K7AAY is it something related to the DVD itself or the windows? I can install a new windows.

Comment: @TheAwesome98 I tried to format but the desk space is still full. Actually, I didn't try to copy the files again because the option "Write to desk" or "Burn to desk" doesn't exist when I right click inside the DVD.

Comment: you need to use a new disc